# mapping json array to ko throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am newbie to knockoutjs . i was trying to map json data to ko.  This is my code.

I want to parse the json data and display it in the table. When i am trying ko.compute it throws me self.firstName() is not an function. When i try to log the value of the firstName in console before compute function, it prints the 3 values in the json array and runs the forurth time and throws an error saying self.firstName is not an function.

**Edit :When i remove computed and just print the data as in the json it is able to map correctly. the issue occurs when i use computed.
When i try console.log(self.firstName() ) before computed and after mapping it prints the values in the jsonarray but instead of parsing 3 times its parses 4 times and 4th time it gives me the "not a function" error**

```
<div id="employeeList">
 <table border ="2">
  <thead>
   <tr>
<th> First Name</th>
<th> Last Name</th>
<th> Age</th>
<th> Phone</th>
<th> Email</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody  data-bind="foreach:employees">
<tr>
 <td data-bind="text:name"></td>
<td data-bind="text:firstName"></td>
<td data-bind="text:lastName"></td>
<td data-bind="text:age"></td>
<td data-bind="text:phone"></td>
<td data-bind="text:email"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

This is my js code

```
     var personMapping={
          'copy':['age'],
          'employees': {
              create: function(options) {
                return new PersonViewModel(options.data);
            }
          }
     };


  function PersonViewModel(data){
      var self=this;
      ko.mapping.fromJS(data,personMapping,this);
       self.name=ko.computed(function(){
          return self.firstName()+' '+self.lastName();
      },this);


  }



var data={employees:
       [{
            firstName: 'Marco',
            lastName: 'Franssen',
            age: 26,
            phone: 12346789,
            email: "a@a.com"    
        },
        {
            firstName: 'Kumar',
            lastName: 'Rangarajan',
            age: 26,
            phone: 123467890,
            email: "a@b.com"
        },
        {
            firstName: 'A',
            lastName: 'B',
            age: 26,
            phone: 6775675567567,
            email: "a@c.com"}]
}

ko.applyBindings(new PersonViewModel(data), $('#employeeList'));


});
```

This is the jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/YfqPs/1/

Comment: Your viewmodel is `PersonViewModel` what you use in `ko.applyBindings` but in your `personMapping` you are also using the `PersonViewModel`... is this typo? What do you want to achieve with this? Some kind of recursive mapping? By the way your fiddle is not working jquery and the mapping plugin are missing from it...

Comment: `console.log(this);` inside `PersonViewModel`. I think it will probably be the `personMapping` which is likely your problem.

Comment: I wanted to create my own mapping. Hence i created personmapping where  i do not want to make age as an observable and created employees to map to my employees in foreach. I saw this was one of the ways it could be done .

Comment: @Pricey : i did not want to do an observable for each of the variables. hence i tried mapping. Yes when i created firstName as an observable i did not have problem using computed. But i wanted everything except age to be an observable. And i do not how to map in that condition.

Comment: @KumarR yea I took that out of my comment because i forgot mapping does it for you. I would recommend you try `console.log(this);` though... see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this and about Object methods.

Comment: @Pricey : when i tried console.log(this) it printed an empty PersonViewModel object.

Comment: @KumarR If you only see it once then your mapping create function isn't working properly. You should also be doing `ko.applyBindings(PersonViewModel, $('#employeeList'));`

Comment: @Pricey : i did console.log in wrong place. when i try console.log(this) after mapping, it gives me copied properties as age and mapped properties as the three arrays but in observe it is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code gets executed 4 times because your are reusing your `PersonViewModel` as your main view model and your view model in your `personMapping`:

- Your `PersonViewModel` get called 3 items once for each item in your `employees` array resulting of this call:

  ```
  create: function(options) {
     return new PersonViewModel(options.data);
  }
  ```
- Your `PersonViewModel` get called for the 4 time resulting of this call:

  ```
  ko.applyBindings(new PersonViewModel(data), $('#employeeList'));
  ```

  and this time it throws the exception because there is no `firstName` property on your main `data` only on your employees.

There are multiple ways to fix this but all of them require to create a proper standalone "main" viewmodel.

The easiest solution is to create your "main" viewmodel with `var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, personMapping);` and use it in your `ko.applyBindings`:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, personMapping);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#employeeList')[0]);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/YfqPs/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you let me know whether there is another way to achieve what i am trying to achieve without the creation of  main view model

Comment: You cannot reuse the same function `PersonViewModel` for your `employeeList` and for also the individual employees. You need to have two viewmodels to make it work. Here is an alternative solution with two named viewmodels:  http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/YfqPs/7/ Here is another solution where your `PersonViewModel` is your "main" viewmodel:  http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/J9r4K/

Answer (score 0):

In your `data`, the `firstName` is under `employees`.

Looks like you should make the call like:

```
return new PersonViewModel(options.data.employees);
```

The view model that contains `ko.computed` should accept a single employee and do the calculation.

```
function PersonViewModel(employee){
   var self=this;
   self.name=ko.computed(function(){
      return self.firstName()+' '+self.lastName();
  },this);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blaise_liu/YfqPs/4/)

Comment: When i remove computed and just print the data as in the json it is able to map correctly. the issue occurs when i use computed.

Comment: the problem is your `self` is `data`, which has no `firstName` as its property.

Comment: But when i print self.firstName() before computed it is correctly printing the values in json array. But it makes 4 parses instead of 3 and in the fourth parse it throws the not a function error

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to get your jsfiddle working with the relevant external dependencies.. so for now I would suggest you don't use the mapping or try this mapper which is meant to be superseding it http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/

What I was expecting is that your calling the `create` function from the context of the `personMapping` object because it is a property on that object.

Which means that in the below code, I would have thought that `this` is actually `personMapping` and not a `PersonViewModel`, which means that your `mapping.fromJS` is trying to map `personMapping` to itself.

```
var self=this;
ko.mapping.fromJS(data,personMapping,this);
```